# global array initialization with a variable element

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I want to initialize an array in global with a particular element as variable

```
unsigned char SlotID;
unsigned char array[]= {SlotID,0x8,0x5,0x3};
main()
{
  slotID= getslotid();// some function to get the value of slot id

}
```

I am getting error while compiling that `slotID` is not constant.
Please tell what do I need to do. SlotID value I will retrieve from getslotid function and accordingly I pass array value to some other function.

Comment: want to use array in other modules as well

Comment: What do you want to achieve this way actually?

Comment: You're not initializing `SlotID` explicitly, so use `unsigned char array[]= {0x0,0x8,0x5,0x3};`

Comment: actually i am working on a system which reads the slotid from the hardware and then it communicates with other module where slotid is the header. It will be different for different cards and hence i want to keep it as a variable

Comment: @sourav i want to get the value of SlotID in runtime and then pass the array[] to a diff module

Comment: @user249520 Ask a new question please.

Comment: @user249520 Once after initialization the array won't be changed anyway. You cannot do it this way.

Comment: thanks. got it. i have to do a diff way